# Visual Studio 2012 RC - C# Template Extensions not Running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

**Quick Question Version:**

Editor Text Adornment template does not run in the launched experimental instance when debugging.

Also cannot hit break points.

**More Detail Question Version:**

So I've been messing around with the Visual Studio 2012 Extension SDK and it seems that when I create a template Editor Text Adornment template and try running it my experimental Visual Studio gets launched but I can't hit any break points and my extension does not run.

The Editor Text Adornment template puts a scarlet box behind all the a's in the document that your working on and none of that happens in my experimental instance. Heck I can't even hit any break points as if the extension is loaded at all.

**What I've done:**

I've done a lot of research on the issue and I've reset my Visual Studio 2012 experimental instance, I've verified that I have my command line arguments are: `/rootsuffix Exp` and lastly i've tried running everything in Administrator

Comment: No ideas from anyone? =(

Comment: A few things to check: Is this an extension you are upgrading from VS2010 or is it brand new? If it's brand new, can you confirm that the extension is definitely being deployed to C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0Exp\Extensions? If it is, does the vsixmanifest include VS11 in the list of SupportedProducts?